# Recover the state of a versioned file that hasn't been committed

Tags: macos, svn, commit, recovery, reverting

Is it possible to recover the state of a versioned file, if I accidentally updated before committing? I said everything was my conflict. I'm using OSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating uncommitted files will not overwrite your changes by default. Your changes are not lost unless you told Subversion to discard them (see next paragraph). If you had conflicts reported, you need to [resolve them yourself](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve), tell Subversion that you've resolved them, then commit the changes.

If, in looking at the conflicts, you responded "theirs-full", your changes are completely lost, because you told Subversion to do so.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I did, I responded "theirs-full", which was the right action, but overlooked this one file. However, where SVN failed, the Time Machine came to rescue. I managed to recover my file. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Some svn clients *may* put the file in the trash/recycle bin/whatever.  I feel like svn should have an undo button somewhere, or keep the last few deleted files in a holding area by default.

Comment: @AlexMA in this case, it wasn't a "delete" - it was an overwrite through a conflict resolution choice made by the OP. In this kind of scenario, what would the expected action if one were to "restore" the file? Revert the file back to a conflicted state? What if further changes are made to the file after that point? It becomes a very messy problem to attempt to solve.